# Completion of a field at some point

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

What does it mean by

(A) the completion of a field $F$ at some $ v \in F$? and

(B) valuation ring at $v$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra), but $v$ won't be an element of $F$ in general.

Comment: I am getting the Definitions but I am not getting the Definitions with " at some point $v$" ?